# JS Найти объект из массива по значению поля

Tags: javascript, массивы

У меня есть такой массив:

```
[
    {
        category: 'frist',
        configName: 'name',
        description: 'opisanie',
        Icon: 'path to icon'
    },
    {
        category: 'second2',
        configName: 'name2',
        description: 'opisanie2',
        Icon: 'path to icon2'
    },
    {
        category: 'third',
        configName: 'name3',
        description: 'opisanie3',
        icon: 'path to icon3'
    }
]
```

я прохожу map-ом по другому массиву и получаю `item.configName`.

Как мне получить `icon` из первого массива, зная `item.configName`, то есть по сути мне нужно получить объект по полю `icon` типа `obj.icon`.

До этого я сделал вот так

```
arr.find(el => el.configName === row.tool)?.icon
```

и это работает, но, как я понимаю, здесь идет перебор элементов, а можно как-то сделать без перебора?

Comment: arr.find(item => item.configName === arr[1].configName)
      ?.icon. Вот так я получаю нужный мне путь до иконки, но как сделать это без метода find и возможно ли ведь arr - это массив объектов

Comment: Нет, не получится, по массиву придется бегать. Есть еще вариант, превратить ваш массив в объект, тогда вы получите, практически, прямой доступ к данным. Это целесообразно, есть массив у вас справочник и не меняется(или редко), а map используете часто